# Inherent shift press in keyboard events in Selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My application has a check box that gets checked using 'Shift' key. When I fired 'Ctrl + F', another short cut in my application, using Selenium Web Driver, the check box got checked automatically. However it worked fine when I used 'Ctrl + f'. This indicates that Shift is getting pressed by web driver inherently. 
When I manually pressed Ctrl+Shift+f, the check box did not get checked. Can some one please explain what could be happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score -1):

If you have used the Shift key in another test that has run before the one you are talking about, the Shift key will remain active until you sent the Keys.Null key.

I recommend sending the Keys.Null key before every test to ensure no modifierkeys remain pressed.